# do while loop with nested if statements not exiting in c++

Tags: c++

OKay, so I'm new to the whole do while loop thing, and I'm trying to make a main menu, here's my code below:

```
int main()
{
    int choice;
    char sure;
    bool quit = false;
    char ctrl;

    do
    {
        cout << "Main Menu." << endl
             << "1. New Game." << endl
             << "2. Load Game." << endl
             << "3. Exit." << endl
             << "Your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            cout << "Are you sure you wish to start a new game? (Y/N) ";
            cin >> sure;

            if (sure != 'N' || sure != 'n')
            {
                ctrl = 'a';
                quit = true;
            }
        }
        else if ( choice == 2)
        {
            ctrl = 'b';
            quit = true;
        }
        else
            quit = true;

        }
    }
    while (quit == true);

    if (ctrl = 'a')
         cout << "New Game." << endl;
    else if (ctrl = 'b')
         cout << "Load Game." << endl;
    else
         cout << "Goodbye." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

there are a few getchar() thrown in there. But the only problem is as you'll probably figure out is that after I do everything it just restarts again, and not exit the loop. What is the problem in the code?

Thanks

Comment: ¤ The main problem is that you didn't fix what I commented on last time you posted. When you don't fix it, it's going to *continue* to be wrong. Just to give you the opportunity to get on track, replace `while(quit == true)` with `while(!quit)`, and start thinking about what that means for the rest of the code. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Don't just replace the wrong code with the correct one. The answers and the question itself won't make any sense anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I think you meant `while (quit != true);`

And remember, comparison is done with `==`, `if (ctrl = 'a')` assigns `'a'` to `ctrl`..

Comment: I don't normally upvote the not-first correct answer, but the extra information in this totally deserves it. It effectively preempts the OP's next question in 10 minutes!

Answer (score 4):

You are not setting `quit` to false anywhere and your loop runs while quit equals true. You need to get the meaning of your boolean values straight or simply change the while part to `while(!quit)`. I'd rather to the first.

Comment: I have ... bool quit = false; :L

Comment: @user1079559 But you set it to true every time you actually want to quit. Read everything out loud: quit is false; now do statements and set quit to true under some conditions; repeat this while quit equals true. The flaw becomes obvious as soon one of the conditions to set quit is met.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you just change

```
    while (quit == true);
```

to

```
    while (quit != true);
```

?

Maybe you know it, but I'll just repeat how

```
do{
//...
} while(condition)
```

loop works. You iterate until the condition is *false*. In your case it was *always* true, that's why you had an infinite loop.

P.S. Take a loot at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8379171/1008481) also. Yet another error was described there.

Imroved code with hopefully all corrected mistakes is [here](http://ideone.com/olcGD).

Comment: I've done that and I guess I've gotten out of the loop but the command prompt is not just exiting despite putting getchar() on the if (ctrl == ... ) part at the code.

Any idea's?

Comment: @user1079559 be sure to correct  `if(ctrl = 'a')` and `if(ctrl = 'b')`. Also delete `}` just before `while`! It works fine for me! Now you are on your own :)

Comment: done all of that and it's still the same problem XD it's probably so stupidly simple, I'll post the code I have now.